# I am using twilio for 'forwarding calls to email ' When i receive the recording it doesn't show for which twilio number the recording is for

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio account for 'forwarding calls to email ' feature ,created a bin as per twilio site. When i receive the call recording to my email address it doesn't show for which twilio number the recording is for . Because i have many twilio numbers and i receive many emails in a day so its very difficult to figure out to which twilio number the recording is for ?

Here is the bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Record action="mail.php" />
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I assume you are talking about this guide for [forwarding call recordings to your email](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132287-Forwarding-Recordings-to-your-email).

To include the number that the call was made to, you just need to update the code in `mail.php` to include the `To` parameter from [Twilio's request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request). I've included the line

```
$message .= "The call came from {$_REQUEST['To']}.\n";
```

in the code below:

```
<?php

/**
* This section ensures that Twilio gets a response.
*/

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; 
echo '<Response></Response>'; // Place the desired response (if any) here.

/**
* This section actually sends the email.
*/

/* Your email address. */
$to = "your-email@example.com";
$subject = "Message from {$_REQUEST['From']}";
$message = "You have received a message from {$_REQUEST['From']}.\n";
$message .= "The call came from {$_REQUEST['To']}.\n";
$message .= "To listen to this message, please visit this URL: {$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com"; // Who should it come from?
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .yes i was exactly using the same guide . For which i have created a bin which would automatically call that mail.php. But where to make the changes ? where can i find this file ? I am a new c# developer and know basics.Please let me know if you have any steps to achieve this task.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the modified bin 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">Thank you for calling abc.Please leave a message after the tone.</Say>
    <Record playBeep="true" action="mail.php"/>
</Response>

Comment: You don't need to change the TwiML. You need to change the file you saved as `mail.php` from that guide. You need to update it to the code above. Where is your `mail.php` hosted?